# What is the difference between mean, mean weight, median, and median weight?

Tags: statistics, means

I'm using an introductory statistics textbook and it mentioned this:

"The "center" of a data set is also a way of describing location. The two most widely used measures of the "center" of the
data are the mean (average) and the median. To calculate the mean weight of 50 people, add the 50 weights together and
divide by 50. To find the median weight of the 50 people, order the data and find the number that splits the data into two
equal parts."

Comment: The two statistical measures are the mean and the median.  It just happens that in this problem the data are weights, hence the mean weight and median weight.  If we were dealing with income instead of weight we would talk about the mean income and median income.  The problem statement tells you how to compute the mean and median.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Mean weight and median weight are just the mean and median. In this case we're talking about weight. We could say mean age, mean height, mean length, if we were talking about something else.

The mean is the numerical average, while the median is the middle element in an ordered data set.